# How can I fix this error: "Library not found for -lGTMSessionFetcher"

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I build a Virtual Reality project in unity on my MacBook Pro and when the time comes to run the project in the Xcode to placed in my iPhone I get the following error:

> Library not found for -lGTMSessionFetcher

[image]

I'm not a programmer I'm a designer and I am designing my final year project in unity

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/539#issuecomment-294738041):

> I finally found out that i had to open the xcworkspace instead of the xcodeproj. Using the xcworkspace, there is a "Pods" that is added and compiled before the unity project.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried doing the pods run but it didn’t seems to help.